# how to fetch twice using getStaticProps? Data is not being pushed into variable

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm fetching data from PokeAPI to my personal project and I need to fetch twice, first to get a Pokemon list which give me a list of Pokemon name with the range I specify, in this case 0 to 20 and then I map this data to fetch specific data for each of these 20 Pokemon but it is not working.

The fetching process is working, I can see everything on console if I set console.log(res), but I can't push data into the products variable, how should I handle it?

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    let products: any = [];
    const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20&offset=0');
    const list = await response.json();

    list.results.map((e: any) => {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${e.name}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            products.push(res);
            console.log(e.name);
        })
    })

    
    return {
        props: {products,},
    }
}
```

I already tried async/await method, tried wrap map into an IIFE, wrap everything in try/catch but nothing of this work, I can return the first fetch (list) but the second one returns empty array.

Comment: The issue you are you returning before the map is finished, you need to await the values.

Comment: Array methods are not promise aware. Use `Promise.all` so you can wait for all the promises to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE what [@ivanatias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17195992/ivanatias) said

You want to first make all the promises, then await their result and return.

I would also recommend adding a catch here in case they fail.

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20&offset=0');
    const list = await response.json();

    const promises = list.results.map((pokemon: any) => {
        return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`).then(res => res.json());
    })

    const pokemon = await Promise.all(promises);

    return {
        props: {
            pokemon
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to add `try/catch` in `getStaticProps`. Exceptions should be unhandled there and let Next.js do its thing. What OP should definitely do is check for the `ok` property of the response and throw an error in case it's `false`.